# The property includeHiddenPages is not working while calling exporttofile API in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have embedded Power BI into my application (embed for customer). Whenever I use **exporttofile** API to export Power BI reports, it always includes the hidden pages. As per the [exporttofile API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#exportreportsettings), if we set IncludeHiddenPages to False, it will exclude the hidden pages. But it is not working.

```
var powerBIReportExportConfiguration = new PowerBIReportExportConfiguration
    {
        Settings = new ExportReportSettings
        {
            Locale = "en-us",
            IncludeHiddenPages = false
        },
        Pages = pageNames?.Select(pn => new ExportReportPage(pn)).ToList()
    };
```

Please note that, I have been used .NET Core to embed Power BI into my application.

Answer (score 0):

`ExportReportRequest` contains `PowerBIReportExportConfiguration` property where we can control to include hidden pages or not. Here is the code

```
var exportRequest = new ExportReportRequest {

      Format : ExportFileFormat,

      powerBIReportExportConfiguration = new PowerBIReportExportConfiguration

            {
                Settings = new ExportReportSettings
                {
                    Locale = "en-us",
                    IncludeHiddenPages = false
                },
                Pages = pageNames?.Select(pn => new ExportReportPage(pn)).ToList()
            };};

Export export = pbiClient.Reports.ExporttofileInGroup(workspaceId, ReportId, exportRequest);
```

#### Reference

*[ExportReportRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file-in-group#exportreportrequest)*